# PyQt4 - can't get video to run with QMovie or Phonon

Tags: python-2.7, animation, video, pyqt4, phonon

I'm having problems getting any video player to work with my PyQt4 setup (having tried both phonon and QMovie). The below QMovie script is from an example where several users commented it as functional. For me, it runs but only opens a window (with `Loading...` centered) that never actually plays the .gif (I've tried several working .gif files from numerous examples online, so the file is not the problem). I've commented out the results from running the three debugging steps as well.

What can I do next?

```
import sys
import os
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class BusyLabel(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, gif, parent = None, text = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.hlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hlayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.hlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.hlayout)

        # Movie
        self.movieLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.movieLabel.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.movieLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.movie = QtGui.QMovie(gif, QtCore.QByteArray(), self)
        self.movie.setScaledSize(QtCore.QSize(20,20))
        self.movie.setCacheMode(QtGui.QMovie.CacheAll)
        self.movie.setSpeed(100)
        print self.movie.isValid() #output = False
        print self.movie.supportedFormats() #output = []

        self.movieLabel.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.movieLabel)

        # Label
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(text)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.movie.start()

    def setText(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)

    def start(self):
        self.show()
        self.movie.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.hide()
        self.movie.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gif = 'test1.gif'
    print os.path.exists(gif) #output = True
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = BusyLabel(gif)
    player.setText('Loading...')
    player.start()
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`output: 
True
False
[]`

(For those curious about my other attempts, running a popular Phonon script gave the error: `phonon backend plugin could not be loaded`... I'll take anything at this point)

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm running on a macOS High Sierra, v10.13.3

Comment: @eyllanesc any ideas given my setup?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that you do not have the backend installed: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/phonon-overview.html#backends: *QuickTime on MaC*

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you - I'm looking into how to get this done on macOS, but for this topic, it's a jungle of online forums with lots of failed attempts. Will keep on going today, but have even considered now creating my own video player class from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm providing here complete, working code that I've written to answer this (my) problem. All you need is `PyQt4` and `Matplotlib`, I hope this might help someone else facing similar troubles down the road:

https://github.com/evanseitz/PyQt4_VideoPlayer